# Send ethernet/udp packet via CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl

How to send ethernet packets or UDP packets via CAPL? I know there is an ethernet IG block but I wanted to know if we can send it via capl script just like a CAN messagee is sent via CaPL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may indeed send ethernet packets through CAPL.

> With option .Ethernet several APIs are provided for receiving and transmitting Ethernet frames.

*The CAPL Function guide.*

For instance, the function `ethernetPacket` is used to create an Ethernet send object. Unfortunately, I've never done it myself, so I don't have a snippet to demostrate this, yet I urge you to refer to the CANoe/CANalyzer guide under section `CAPL Functions` > `Ethernet CAPL Functions`. Interrupt-like procedures are also provided for Ethernet communication, e.g. `on ethernetPacket`. In addition, you might want to put some more effort in the research, next time...

---

I know nothing of UDP, yet for sake of completeness CAPL provides APIs for TCP/IP, FlexRay, RS232 (serial), and standards like J1939, K-Line.

Answer (score 1):

Function `ethernetPacket <packet var>;` can be used to create an Ethernet send object. The object data can be manipulated by selectors associated with this object. More information about these selectors can be found in Help at the following path:
CAPL Functions » Ethernet » ethernetPacket

Here an example on how to send a Ethernet Packet via CAPL

```cpp
ethernetPacket txPacket;
int i;

txPacket.msgChannel = 1;
txPacket.hwChannel = 2;
txPacket.source = EthGetMacAddressAsNumber( "20:00:00:00:00:01" );
txPacket.destination = EthGetMacAddressAsNumber( "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF" );
txPacket.Length = 100;
txPacket.type = 0xF123;

for( i = 0; i < txPacket.Length; i++ )
{
  txPacket.Byte(i) = i & 0xFF;
}
output( txPacket );
```